# Change project name when releasing next version Android

Tags: android, package, version, project

Very simple question.

I have application with project name come.foot.ball and i have released this on google play. Now i want to change this name with com.brazil.football on new next version of my application.

Is it possible and people how would update this application on thier gadjets would have no problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is not possible. The package name identifies the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the bundle identifier(package name) of your app once it has been uploaded on play store.